# How to load some views from database, and others from files in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, virtualpathprovider

Im having a web application that loads _Layout and the normal page views from file, and I now try to load partial views from a database using a VirtualPathProvider and an overriden VirtualFile:

```
public class RavenDbPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider {

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath) {
        if (!virtualPath.StartsWith("TextContents/")) return false;

        using (var session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDocumentSession>()) {
            return session.Query<TextContent>().Any(w => w.Id == virtualPath);
        }
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath) {
        if (!virtualPath.StartsWith("TextContents/")) 
            return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        return new RavenDbVirtualFile(virtualPath);
    }
}
```

I also register the Provider in global.asax:

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new RavenDbPathProvider());
```

However, when I register the RavenDbPathProvider It seems that it gets used for all view lookups.

Is it possible to register multiple VirtualPathProviders so that if a view cant be found on disk the search will continue in the database?

If not, has anyone done something similar to this with success?

Comment: Don't you want your `FileExists` method to also call (and return) the base `FileExists` if it's not within `TextContents` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I changed to return the base implementation and came a few steps futher. I also needed to modify the virtual path to actually find the views, but after that I was home. Thanks!